# Hide/Prevent empty returned items

Tags: jquery, frontend

I am attempting to create a toggle element that switches between a grid and a table when clicking an outside element. Most of my functionality is present however, when the 'table' & 'grid' links are selected more than once, multiple empty divs/tr's are being returned.

How can I prevent this from occurring before the return? If not that, then how would I hide the empty returned elements?

Please bear in mind, this will need to be compatible in IE8+.

Fiddle below. Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/rymill2/EeRu4/5/

```
$('.button-table').click(function () {
    $('.grid').replaceWith(function () {
        var html = '';
        $('div:first', this).each(function () {
            html += '<tr class="table-head">';
            $('div', this).each(function () {
                html += '<th>' + $(this).html() + '</th>';
            });
            html += '</tr>';
        });
        $('div:not(:first)', this).each(function () {
            html += '<tr>';
            $('div', this).each(function () {
                html += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });
            html += '</tr>';
        });
        return '<table>' + html + '</table>';
    });
});

$('.button-grid').click(function () {
    $('table').replaceWith(function () {
        var html = '';
        $('tr', this).each(function () {
            html += '<div class="result three columns h-100">';
            $('th', this).each(function () {
                html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
            });
            $('td', this).each(function () {
                html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
            });
            html += '</div>';
        });
        return '<div class="grid">' + html + '</div>';
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be better to approach this as having two views of the same data, rather than parsing data out of one structure to build the other. Knockout (knockoutjs.com) might be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, I started on some tutorials and I am beginning to see where this may be of value. Hopefully I can tailor it to my current situation.

Comment: I would just toggle a class on the container (``<ul>`` or ``<div``) and do the rest with CSS.

(The JSFiddle link is broken, by the way.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rymill2/R3J5m/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to figure this out while still utilizing jQuery. The only CSS dependent piece is:

```
.grid .result:first-child {display:none;}
```

This hides the TH tagged items from the grid view.

Otherwise, all I had to do was add an IF statement to the table button's toggle and add an extra variable (innerHtml).

Here is the final code and link to the repaired fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rymill2/R3J5m/

```
$('.button-table').click(function() {
    $('.grid').replaceWith(function() {
        var html = '';
        $('div:first', this).each(function() {
            html += '<tr class="table-head">';
            $('div', this).each(function() {
                html += '<th>' + $(this).html() + '</th>';
            });
            html += '</tr>';
        });   
        $('div:not(:first)', this).each(function() {
            var innerHtml = '';
            $('div', this).each(function() {
                innerHtml += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });
            if (innerHtml != '') {
            html += '<tr>' + innerHtml + '</tr>';
            }
        });
        return '<table>' + html + '</table>'; 
    });
});

$('.button-grid').click(function() {
    $('table').replaceWith(function() {
        var html = '';      
        $('tr', this).each(function() {
            html += '<div class="result three columns h-100">';
            $('th', this).each(function() {
                html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
            });
            $('td', this).each(function() {
                html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
            });
            html += '</div>';
        });
        return '<div class="grid">' + html + '</div>';
    });
});
```